# Thymeleaf doesn't find message source

Tags: spring, configuration, thymeleaf

I'm actually confused about a part of my Thymeleaf configuration.

I have a property file located at `classpath:/messages/web.properties`. In my configuration the following is defined.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    final ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;

    messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setBasename("messages/web");

    return messageSource;
}
```

If I run my application with this configuration everything works fine. The messages from the properties file are injected into the Thymeleaf template (as expected).

But if I change the name of the method which creates my message source, restart my application and request the same page... then the messages from my `web.properties` file are not found.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource webMessageSource() {
    [...]
}
```

Why the bean name (= method name) of the message resource has this impact to my application?

Why the message source `webMessageSource` could not be found by the Thymeleaf template engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a little digging around in the Thymeleaf source code, I found that in the class `SpringTemplateEngine` the [Javadoc](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf-spring4/2.1.3.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/spring4/SpringTemplateEngine.html) clearly states:

> It also configures a {@link SpringMessageResolver} as message
>   resolver, and implements the {@link MessageSourceAware} interface in
>   order to let Spring  automatically setting the {@link MessageSource}
>   used at the application (bean needs to have id
>   "messageSource"). If this Spring standard setting needs to be
>   overridden, the {@link #setTemplateEngineMessageSource(MessageSource)}
>   can be used.

The important part is **bean needs to have id "messageSource"**

As noted by @ShinichiKai, [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource) part of the Spring documentation mentions that the name of the MessageSource bean in Spring must be `messageSource`.

Comment: This behavior comes from the ApplicationContext implementation. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource) it says "The bean must have the name messageSource".